# Difference between 2 lists of objects in Java

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a obj type `MyObj` as follow:

```
  class MyObj{
    String id;
    String username;
    String fullName;
    String age;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Suppose we have 2 lists containing different number of elements like so:

```
List<MyObj> listA
List<MyObj> listB
```

I have a generic method that detects elements from `listA` that are missing in `listB`:

```
 public static <T> List<T> getListDifference(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        Collection<T> first = new HashSet<T>(list1);
        Collection<T> second = new HashSet<T>(list2);
        first.removeAll(second);
        return new ArrayList<T>(first);
    }
```

If objects from `listA` and `listB` has the same fields for all items, everything works just fine.

The problem is that some items has only `id` and `username` but others can have `fullName` or `age` too, and as result this method doesn't work anymore. I'd like to keep the same logic, considering only `id` field because it's present in all objects.

One obvious method is to copy only object's `id` field in other `List<String>` and work with obtained lists to detect elements, then just search for obj from both lists by `id`. This method has a big complexity, because of multiple iterations. Is there a short way to achieve this?

Comment: override `MyObj#equals` and `MyObj#hashCode`

Comment: I think the question is not Android related at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ Kevin Esche mentioned, you have to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in your `MyObj` POJO, and according to your situation, they should be:

```
   @Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof MyObj)) return false;

    MyObj myObj= (MyObj) obj;
    return Objects.equals(id, myObj.id);
}
```

That will work even if ages are different and the ids are the same for example.

Comment: `if (!(obj instanceof MyObj))` should be replaced by `if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass())`. Because if two data objects have different class, they're obviously not identical.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement `equals` and `hashCode` to work with sets. Sets needs a way of recognising if one object is equal to another, and default behaviour is not gonna work here.

By the way, I suggest using `retainAll` method on a list, [check this out.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)

Answer (score 2):

override MyObjs `equals` method:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    MyObj myObj = (MyObj) o;

    return (id != null ? !id.equals(myObj.id) : myObj.id != null);
}
```

IntelliJ/Android Studio have helpers for automatically generating `equals` and `hashCode` where you can choose the necessary properties.